# How to install Mule ESB community runtime 3.7.0 to anypointstudio 6.1.0

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I have just downloaded new version of anypointstudio i.e. 6.1.0 and it came with default 3.8.1 community runtime and for my project I need to add 3.7.0 . But I can not find it in market place and when I downloaded mule ESB 3.7.0 runtime standalone and trying to add it from Windows -> preferences - > server - > runtime and adding it . It s saying there is no server runtime found in the folder . Please help me in this way , would be a great help . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help-> Install New software -> click Add -> Use this url http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/updates. It have lower versions,
Since you downloaded directly 3.8 you can see
http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/updates sites. Version 3.7 present in r4

More details follow the link. 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/5/studio-update-sites.

Edited My Question: Use Studio RunTime Url ->

http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/
[image]

Comment: I have tried these options .. It has 3.7.0 runtime .. but not community edition . I need to install commmunity version 3.7.0 mule runtime. Can you suggest something please

Comment: I have also tried these options even using this link http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/studio-runtimes/ .. but it lists only three versions 3.4.0 , 3.5.0 & 3.6.1 .. nothing else .

Comment: If you able to see CE version of these 3.4.0 , 3.5.0 & 3.6.1   except 3.7. Verify in your studio, would have already been installed it. Right Click on Project ->Run-us ->Run Configuration ( It will list all the servers which you have installed in Target Server RunTime).

Comment: I restarted my anypointstudio and then somehow magically 3.7.0 appears in community list (it was not installed in runtimes earlier ) which I have installed but when I am trying to run my application with 3.7.0 CE now ..It is showing a different error . "You can not run an application with datamapper in mule esb community edition " .. but what I know is datamapper is only enterprise feature .. please tell me how to overcome this issue .

Comment: The error is self-explicit. Using a community edition runtime (that is non-enterprise edition), you cannot use enterprise-only component such as datamapper.

Comment: Its a different issue from the question.By the way,You are trying to use CE Version and excepting EE version of DM.Please refer the url http://www.whishworks.com/blog/mule-esb/mule-esb-community-vs-enterprise-edition/